# Emacs org files encryption in MS Windows

Tags: encryption, emacs, org-mode, gnupg, ergoemacs

I would like to encrypt my org files(org-mode) or a region of the file in emacs. The option given in the tool does not work (gives me the error apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, gpg). I guess because I am using emacs on windows and all the search on this topic point towards encrypting the files on UNIX platform. Can you please help me on how encryption can be achieved on windows. Thanks in advance.

I am using ergoemacs for windows downloaded from http://ergoemacs.org/index.html. The version is as follows:

GNU Emacs 24.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) of 2012-08-29 on MARVIN ErgoEmacs distribution 2.0.0

Comment: I solved the problem by using cygwin for windows and using cygwin-mount.el. Let me know if you require more information regarding the same,

Answer (score 2):

Install GnuPG onto your Windows machine. Binary versions (i.e. ones that you don't have to compile yourself) are available from http://gpg4win.org/.

Once GnuPG is installed, and assuming you add its binary directory to your Windows `%PATH%`, Emacs should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

solved the problem by installing cygwin (which has GPG installed) and using the same in emacs.

This can be done by giving the cgywin installed directory in the option cygwin-root-directory of the emacs editor